# Android - Show alert dialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, authentication, android-asynctask, show, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an alert dialog when a user fails to enter valid email and password to log in. Since the login process has to deal with HTTP request and JSON, I put it all in an AsyncTask and I'm not sure if that's the problem why my alert dialog can't show (I hope not). So this is method `checkUser`, which is called within `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask` class:

```
    public void checkUser(JSONObject json){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                if (tag == login_tag){
                    // check for login response
                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                // code omitted
                            } else{
                                // Error in login
                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                builder.setMessage("Incorrect username/password")
                                       .setTitle("Error")
                                       .setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,final int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();                                                    
                                           }
                                        }).create().show();

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Somehow my alert dialog can never show and I don't know why. If you have any idea what the reason of this problem is, please help me out. Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Turns out I only close my `Progress Dialog` after executing this method, so I decided to dismiss it before showing the alert dialog. But it still hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this myself this way: somehow the Alert dialog only works outside the method `checkUser`. So I move the bits within the error if clause outside, below the `dismiss()` of Progress dialog in `onPostExecute()`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            checkUser(json);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                if (json.get(ERROR_MSG) != null){
                    String errorMsg = json.getString(ERROR_MSG);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.setMessage(errorMsg)
                   .setTitle("Error")
                   .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();                                                    
                       }
                    }).create().show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And voila, it works!
P.s: I still don't know why the dialog can't show when put within `checkUser` though.

Answer (score 1):

missing `builder.create()`

```
// Error in login
builder.setMessage("Incorrect username/password")
     .setTitle("Error")
     .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();                                                    
     }
 }).create().show();
```

Comment: @strawberryjam : first make sure control is going inside else block and plz edit your question with latest code

Comment: right, thank you for the suggestion! I just edited my code by adding the `create()` thing, but the problem still remains at the moment.

Comment: @strawberryjam : tag and login_tag is String ?

Comment: @strawberryjam : and if tag and login_tag is String then use if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(login_tag)){...} instead if (tag == login_tag){..

Comment: That's not the problem because when I enter the right email and password the code still works. Only the alert has problem though. But I changed into `equalIgnoreCase` anyway, thank you.

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized that I only close my progress dialog after finishing executing `checkUser`. So I tried dismissing this dialog before showing the alert. But well, it still doesn't work.